# Why does my image not rotate? Code in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a problem with animation in css. Why is the image not rotating?
When I change rotate to opacity the image disappears, but when I give rotate it doesn't move.

Here is my Vue code

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <router-link class="navbar settings" to="/settings"
      ><i class="bi bi-gear-fill"></i> Settings</router-link
    >
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "NavBar",
};
</script>

<style src="../style/navbar.css"></style>
```

And there css:

```
:root {
  --main-color-dark-hover: #0f5e80;
  --main-color-dark: #1b8bbf;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.navbar {
  color: var(--main-color-dark);
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar:hover,
.navbar:active {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--main-color-dark-hover);
  transform: translateY(2.5px);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.navbar.settings:hover .bi-gear-fill {
  transition: rotate 1s;
  rotate: 360deg;
}
```

Comment: You're stating `rotate: 360deg;` This should be `transform: rotate(360deg);` (unless you're using some library not mentioned)

Comment: No, [`rotate: 360deg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/rotate) is perfectly valid.

Comment: add display:inline-block to it